# Как сделать в поле image его полный url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Как сделать в поле image его полный url? Должен быть таким: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/mz16.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `SerializerMethodField`

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name','image', 'description') 

    def get_image(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        image_url = obj.image.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(image_url)
```

Comment: появилась ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'

Comment: может знаете как пофиксить ее?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить request в context при вызове сериалайзера во вью https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло))